# Weird problem reading XML from URL

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Here's my code:

```
        string url = @"http://eafsys:1234/vp.xml";
        try
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do whatever..
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

When I run it I catch the following error:

'The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine'

I searched the internet and apparently I am supposed to change some web.config file in my IIS. The thing is the system where the XML data comes from doesn't have IIS, it doesn't even have a web server. It's just a program listening on that port waiting to output XML.

I can surf (with a any browser, I.E or FireFox) to http://eafsys:1234/vp.xml and I get nicely formatted XML.

Here is the raw (source view) of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<EAFSTATUS>
<EAST>
<HEAT_NO>100633</HEAT_NO>
<GRADE>EA174  </GRADE>
<HEATSTATUS>MELT</HEATSTATUS>
<CHARGENUM>2</CHARGENUM>
<CRMTEMP>1657</CRMTEMP>
<CRMC> 0.0519</CRMC>
<CHARGE>178000</CHARGE>
<ENERGY>80710</ENERGY>
<ELECTKWH>46400</ELECTKWH>
<POWERONTIME> 33:18</POWERONTIME>
<POWERSTATUS>OFF</POWERSTATUS>
<DELAYDUR>3:18</DELAYDUR>
<DELAYSTATUS>OPEN </DELAYSTATUS>
<DELAYREASON>          NO REASON </DELAYREASON>
</EAST>
<WEST>
<HEAT_NO>100632</HEAT_NO>
<GRADE>EA174  </GRADE>
<HEATSTATUS>REF </HEATSTATUS>
<CHARGENUM>2</CHARGENUM>
<CRMTEMP>1529</CRMTEMP>
<CRMC> 0.0418</CRMC>
<CHARGE>178500</CHARGE>
<ENERGY>95010</ENERGY>
<ELECTKWH>54500</ELECTKWH>
<POWERONTIME> 39:06</POWERONTIME>
<POWERSTATUS>OFF</POWERSTATUS>
<DELAYDUR></DELAYDUR>
<DELAYSTATUS></DELAYSTATUS>
<DELAYREASON></DELAYREASON>
</WEST>
<LMF_EAST>
<HEAT_NO>100631</HEAT_NO>
<GRADE>EA719  </GRADE>
<HEATSTATUS>DONE</HEATSTATUS>
<LMF_TIME> 58:48</LMF_TIME>
<TEMP>1546</TEMP>
<WT>163100</WT>
<SAMP>M03</SAMP>
<SAMP_S>0.005760</SAMP_S>
<CAO>0</CAO>
<AL2O3>0</AL2O3>
</LMF_EAST>
<LMF_WEST>
<HEAT_NO>100632</HEAT_NO>
<GRADE>EA174  </GRADE>
<HEATSTATUS>REF </HEATSTATUS>
<LMF_TIME> 47:42</LMF_TIME>
<TEMP>1566</TEMP>
<WT>167500</WT>
<SAMP>M02</SAMP>
<SAMP_S>0.000000</SAMP_S>
<CAO>0</CAO>
<AL2O3>0</AL2O3>
</LMF_WEST>
<CASTER>
<HEATNUM>100631</HEATNUM>
<OUTBOARDHEATNUM>0</OUTBOARDHEATNUM>
<CASTSPEED>1.295000</CASTSPEED>
<CASTWIDTH>1.365312</CASTWIDTH>
<REMAININGWEIGHT>66714</REMAININGWEIGHT>
<NEXTTIME>15:20:13.00</NEXTTIME>
<HEATDUR>55</HEATDUR><LADLESINSERVICE>4</LADLESINSERVICE></CASTER>
</EAFSTATUS>
```

If anyone has any idea's I'd love to hear them.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `XmlTextReader.Read()` function is looking for a proper HTTP status code.

Comment: I'd suggest to download the XML with WebClient first and then load it into XmlReader as Stream...

Comment: I guess there's more to implementing an HTTP server than just listening on port 80 and waiting to output XML.

Comment: @jnpcl what is this? @Shrike WebClient give me the EXACT same error. @ConradFrix Yeah I'd assume so. But we have been serving html, xml plain text with no issues. My problem only occurs when trying to consume the xml with .net.

Comment: What happens if you have your not-a-server app spit out HTTP headers before the content?

Comment: What do you mean by *It's just a program listening on that port waiting to output XML.*  What does the program listen *for*?  The XmlTextReader() is probably sending it a proper HTTP request, and is throwing because it isn't getting a proper (valid) HTTP response.  You may be able to peek at the message exchange using Fiddler2. (free download, good tool)

Comment: XmlTextReader is a lot simpler than a web browser. You could be missing a cookie or some type of authentication http header that the browser automatically sends out. Best bet is to use Fiddler2 or wireshark to compare what is going out on the wire on the request that works and the request that fails.

Comment: @Cheeso fiddler2 worked wonders found the problem in my HTTP response header. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tell a browser to open a file with a url you are leveraging the local file (or even network) system. The browser actually is capable of opening the file and reading it. When you tell an XmlTextReader to open a file with a URL you are telling it to issue an httpRequest and expect an httpResponse in return, and that requires an internet server of some flavor.

You might be able to substitute a filestreamreader and then feed that stream to the XmlTextReader, but I haven't tried that. You are likely better of servicing that file from an web server or accessing it via a UNC instead of a URL.

Comment: The problem is that the data being served up is on a VMS system with no web server.

Comment: But you should be able to hang a webserver 'near by' (in virtual space) that can accept the httpRequest and get the stream from the VMS and package it to the httpResponse.

Comment: If the URL has a protocol of `http://`, you're telling the browser to issue an HTTP request too. And since he says this is working, it means there is a working web (HTTP) server on that machine.

Comment: @svivk NO.. there is no web server on the machine, I wrote a socket program to listen on port 1234, same could be done for port 80 or 8000 for that matter.

Comment: @carny666...when you say 'I wrote a socket program to listen on port 1234' what you are saying is that you created a simple form of a web server. It takes in an httpRequest (albeit on port 1234 rather than 80) and issues as response in the form of creating a stream back the requestor. With that in mind I would guess that XmlTextReader is issuing a request differently (unlikely, but possible) or it is not prepared to handle the response that it gets from your port listener, where a browser is (most likely). If you can log those activities you will probably find your disconnect.

Comment: @CosCallis that's what I am thinking. Maybe the HTTP header (that we create) is not quite up to snuff and I.E (and firefox) just ignore it while .Net needs it to be just so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error once, although I don't remember whether it was exactly this. Anyway, you can try the solution that worked for me: setting the following property before you download anything:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```